# Javascript function causing error not defined

Tags: javascript, html, function, undefined

I have a simple function that seems to be causing an 'Uncaught ReferenceError: arraySort is not defined' whenever the function is called, in this case by a button and i cant see why any help would be brilliant.

Javascript

```
    <script language="javascript">
        var unsorted = ["Printer","Tablet","Router"];
        var alphaOrder = [" ","A","a","B","b","C","c","D","d","E","e","F","f","G","g",  //15
                          "H","h","I","i","J","j","K","k","L","l","M","m","N","n","O",  //30
                          "o","P","p","Q","q","R","r","S","s","T","t","U","u","V","v",  //45
                          "W","w","X","x","Y","y","Z","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6",  //60
                          "7","8","9","'","?","!",".","\"","<",">","@",",","#","~","=", //75
                          "+","-","_","/","\\"];

        function arraySort(array){
            var sortedArray = [];
            var letterNum = 0;
            var numArray = [];

            function letterToNum(){
                for (var elementNum = 0; elementNum < array.length; elementNum++;){
                    for (var alphaNum = 0; alphaNum < alphaOrder.length; alphaNum++;){
                        numArray[elementNum] = alphaOrder.indexOf(array[elementNum][letterNum]);
                        document.getElementById('tester1').innerHTML = numArray;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    </script>
```

HTML

```
    <button type = "button" onclick = "arraySort(unsorted)">Sort</button>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code?

Comment: sorry accidentally posted it prematurely

Comment: Typo in `language="javascipt"`. You don't need it at all, just do `<script>`.

Comment: omg ive been doing that for years and just got it wrong this time thanks

Comment: what is the correct way just as i know its good practice

Comment: As I said, the "correct" way nowadays is just `<script>` without any attributes.

Comment: Please do not add updates on the question status in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from the end of your loops.

```
for (var elementNum = 0; elementNum < array.length; elementNum++) {
    for (var alphaNum = 0; alphaNum < alphaOrder.length; alphaNum++) {
    }
```

Comment: Tried it but no different

Comment: @Sam Well, first remove your `language="javascipt"`

Comment: Have done ty its solved now but doesn't seem to update when i change it

Comment: @SamThompson it's not his fault that it doesn't sort, that's yours. He answered your question and corrected your uncaught reference error.

Comment: Its no where near finished so im not expecting it to sort yet

Comment: Ignore my preveous comments they came out sounding wrong

Comment: What MuhammadJ  posted originally was needed but not the complete answer so I didnt accept it immediatly

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions here

1. Wrap your logic inside script by `window.onload`
2. Don't mix your markup and javascript.
3. Try binding events at javascript end

Follow the above suggestions, your error will be fixed.

Comment: I need within a button isntead of onload. I dont know what you mean by markup (sorry still new). Ok but as Im doing this for younger students having in the html 'onlick' is simpler so easier to understand.

Comment: but its not a good practice to do it like that...you cannot access unSorted variable at html(markup) end

Comment: yes you can access javascipt varieble in html markup such as onclick or onload

Comment: yes i agree ...im sorry about that